# sqlite query hangs when adding ORDER BY

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm getting some data from a sqlite database, my query works fine until i add the order by clause

my query is structured like this

> SELECT * FROM TESTI WHERE TESTO LIKE '%test%' COLLATE NOCASE LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0

this run fine and i get all the record containing the word test on the first 100 row of the database, but when i add the ORDER BY clause in this way

> SELECT * FROM TESTI WHERE TESTO LIKE '%test%' COLLATE NOCASE LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 ORDER BY ID

the system hangs for an indefinite amount of time (i have to force close)

the Table TESTI has 35000 rows how can i order by id without hang all the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an SQL syntax error. `ORDER BY` should come before `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTI WHERE TESTO LIKE '%test%' COLLATE NOCASE ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Why it hangs is not due to the SQL but your program running it. Likely it cannot recover from a syntax error.